# Entries of the inverse of $\left[\frac{1}{x+i+j-1}\right]_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$ are polynomials in $x$.

Tags: matrices, polynomials, modules, gcd-and-lcm, rational-functions

Let $n$ be a positive integer.  Define $$\textbf{A}_n(x):= \left[\frac{1}{x+i+j-1}\right]_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$$ as a matrix over the field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ of rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$ in variable $x$.

(a) Prove that the *Hilbert matrix* $\textbf{A}_n(0)$ is an invertible matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$ and all entries of the inverse of $\textbf{A}_n(0)$ are integers.

(b) Determine the greatest common divisor (over $\mathbb{Z}$) of all the entries of $\big(\textbf{A}_n(0)\big)^{-1}$.

(c) Show that $\textbf{A}_n(x)$ is an invertible matrix over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ and every entry of the inverse of $\textbf{A}_n(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$.

(d) Prove that $x+n$ is the greatest common divisor (over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) of all the entries of $\big(\textbf{A}_n(x)\big)^{-1}$.

<strike>Parts (a) and (c) are known.</strike>  <strike>Parts (b) and (d) are open.</strike>  <strike>Now, Part (d) is known (see i707107's solution below), but Part (b) remains open, although it seems like the answer is $n$.</strike>

---

Recall that 
$$\binom{t}{r}=\frac{t(t-1)(t-2)\cdots(t-r+1)}{r!}$$
for all $t\in\mathbb{Q}(x)$ and $r=0,1,2,\ldots$.  According to i707107, the $(i,j)$-entry of $\big(\textbf{A}_n(x)\big)^{-1}$ is given by
$$\alpha_{i,j}(x)=(-1)^{i+j}\,(x+n)\,\binom{x+n+i-1}{i-1}\,\binom{x+n-1}{n-j}\,\binom{x+n+j-1}{n-i}\,\binom{x+i+j-2}{j-1}\,.\tag{*}$$
This means that, for all integers $k$ such that $k\notin\{-1,-2,\ldots,-2n+1\}$, the entries of $\big(\textbf{A}_n(k)\big)^{-1}$ are integers.  ***I now have a new conjecture, which is the primary target for the bounty award.***

> **Conjecture:**  The greatest common divisor $\gamma_n(k)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ of the entries of $\big(\textbf{A}_n(k)\big)^{-1}$, where $k$ is an integer not belonging in the set $\{-1,-2,\ldots,-2n+1\}$, is given by $$\gamma_n(k)=\mathrm{lcm}(n,n+k)\,.$$

It is clear from (*) that $n+k$ must divide $\gamma_n(k)$.  However, it is not yet clear to me why $n$ should divide $\gamma_n(k)$.  I would like to have a proof of this conjecture, or at least a proof that $n \mid \gamma_n(k)$.

---

Let $M_n$ denote the (unitary) cyclic $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module generated by $\dfrac{1}{\big((n-1)!\big)^2}\,(x+n)$.  Then, the (unitary)  $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module $N_n$ generated by the entries of $\big(\textbf{A}_n(x)\big)^{-1}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-submodule of $M_n$.

We also denote by $\tilde{M}_n$ for the (unitary)  $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by $\dfrac{1}{\big((n-1)!\big)^2}\,(x+n)\,x^l$ for $l=0,1,2,\ldots,2n-2$.  Then, the (unitary) $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\tilde{N}_n$ generated by the entries of $\big(\textbf{A}_n(x)\big)^{-1}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $\tilde{M}_n$.

For example, $M_2/N_2$ is isomorphic to the (unitary) $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (in which $x$ acts trivially), and $\tilde{M}_2/\tilde{N}_2$ is isomorphic to the (unitary) $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Hence, $\left|M_2/N_2\right|=2=\left|\tilde{M}_2/\tilde{N}_2\right|$.  For $n=3$, Mathematica yields
$$\tilde{M}_3/\tilde{N}_3\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 2}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 3}\,,$$
as abelian groups.  That is, $\left|\tilde{M}_3/\tilde{N}_3\right|=1152$.  On the other hand, 
$$M_3/N_3\cong \mathbb{Z}[x] \big/\left(12,2x^2+6x+4,x^4-x^2\right)$$
as $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-modules, which gives $\left|M_3/N_3\right|=576$.

> **Question:**  Describe the factor $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module $M_n/N_n$ and the factor $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\tilde{M}_n/\tilde{N}_n$.  It is easily seen that $\left|M_n/N_n\right|\leq\left|\tilde{M}_n/\tilde{N}_n\right|$.  What are $\left|M_n/N_n\right|$ and $\left|\tilde{M}_n/\tilde{N}_n\right|$?  It can be shown also that the ratio $\dfrac{\left|\tilde{M}_n/\tilde{N}_n\right|}{\left|M_n/N_n\right|}$ is an integer, provided that $\left|\tilde{M}_n/\tilde{N}_n\right|$ is finite.  Compute $\dfrac{\left|\tilde{M}_n/\tilde{N}_n\right|}{\left|M_n/N_n\right|}$ for all integers $n>0$ such that $\left|\tilde{M}_n/\tilde{N}_n\right|<\infty$.  Is it always the case that $\left|\tilde{M}_n/\tilde{N}_n\right|$ is finite?

***Apart from the conjecture above, this question is also eligible for the bounty award.***  I have not yet fully tried to deal with any case involving $n>3$.  However, for $n=4$, the module $\tilde{M}_4/\tilde{N}_4$ is huge:
$$  \tilde{M}_4/\tilde{N}_4\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 2}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 3}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 2}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 2}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z})$$
as abelian groups.

Comment: What's your question exactly ?

Comment: Parts (b) and (d) are my real questions.  Other parts are important ingredients that can be seen as exercises for those who are interested.

Comment: How did you come up with the conjecture? Did you run some simulations?

Comment: @i707107  Yep, I used Mathematica to observe the pattern.  So far, I haven't found a counterexample yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a solution to (d), and partially for (b).

We use [Cauchy Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix), and its evaluation of inverse given by Schechter:

If $T$ is a $n\times n$ Cauchy matrix on the sequences $\{x_i\}$, $\{y_j\}$, then
$S=T^{-1}=[s_{ij}]$ is given by:

$$s_{ij} = (x_j - y_i) A_j(y_i) B_i(x_j) $$
where
$$A_i(t) = \frac{A(t)}{A^\prime(x_i)(t-x_i)} \quad\text{and}\quad B_i(t) = \frac{B(t)}{B^\prime(y_i)(t-y_i)}$$
with
$$A(t) = \prod_{i=1}^n (t-x_i) \quad\text{and}\quad B(t) = \prod_{i=1}^n (t-y_i). $$

The matrix $\mathbf{A}_n(x)$ is considered as a Cauchy matrix on the sequences 
$$x_i = x+i  \quad\text{and} \quad y_j = -j+1.$$

Using the above inverse formula, the $ij$ entry of the inverse up to sign is 
$$
\frac{ (x+n)\cdot (x+i) \cdots (x+n-1)}{(n-i)!} \frac{ (x+n+1)\cdots (x+n+i-1)}{(i-1)!} \frac{ (x+j) \cdots (x+j+n-1)}{(x+i+j-1)(n-j)!(j-1)!}
$$

We see that every entry is divisible by $x+n$.

To prove that the GCD is $x+n$, we need to prove that any possible factor other than $x+n$ which is present in one entry is not present in some another entry. This is easy to see.

Moreover, the factor $(x+n)^2$ is present for most of times, but it is possible to have only one $x+n$ in the factorization (in case $x+i+j-1= x+n$).

For (b), we use the well known formula for inverse of Hilbert matrix:
$$
(H^{-1})_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}(i+j-1){n+i-1 \choose n-j}{n+j-1 \choose n-i}{i+j-2 \choose i-1}^2
$$
Upon rearranging, we obtain that the $ij$ entry up to sign is
$$
n\frac{(n+i-1)\cdots (n+1)}{(i-1)!} \frac{(n-1)\cdots (n-j+1)}{(j-1)!} \binom{n+j-1}{i+j-1} \binom{i+j-2}{i-1}
$$
which is simplified to
$$
n \binom{n+i-1}{i-1} \binom{n-1}{j-1} \binom{n+j-1}{i+j-1} \binom{i+j-2}{i-1}.
$$
This is clearly divisible by $n$, but I was not able to show that $n$ is the GCD which I conjecture to be.

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution to Part (d).  Incidentally, you have also proved Part (c) (as well as Part (a), sort of).  I hope you don't mind me editing something for clarification.

Comment: For Part (b), I get stuck at the same place.

Comment: I obtained that the GCD is a divisor of $n!$, but it is too much.

Comment: More obviously, the first entry ($11$ entry) is $n^2$, so the GCD is divisible by $n^2$. So, for a special case $n=p$ prime, we have the GCD equal to $p$.

Comment: In the above comment, I meant the GCD is a divisor of $n^2$.

Comment: I know what you meant.  Apparently, the gcd of the first row is already $n$, but I can't yet prove that.

Answer (score 3):

For Part (b), according to i707107's answer, the $(i,j)$-entry of $\textbf{H}_n:=\big(\textbf{A}_n(0)\big)^{-1}$ is given by $$h_{i,j}:=(-1)^{i+j}\,n\,\binom{n+i-1}{i-1}\,\binom{n-1}{j-1}\,\binom{n+j-1}{i+j-1}\,\binom{i+j-2}{i-1}\,.$$
Hence, $n$ is a divisor of the greatest common divisor $g_n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ of the entries of $\textbf{H}_n$.
Note that
$$\left|h_{1,j}\right|=n\,\binom{n-1}{j-1}\,\binom{n+j-1}{j}=n\,\binom{n+j-1}{n-1}\,\binom{n-1}{j-1}=n\,\binom{n+j-1}{j-1}\,\binom{n}{j}\,;$$
in particular,
$$h_{1,1}=n^2\,.$$
Ergo, $$n\mid g_n\mid n^2\,.$$
If $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$ such that $p^k$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$, then using [Lucas's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem), we know that 
$$\binom{n+p^k-1}{p^k-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$$
and
$$\binom{n}{p^k}\equiv \frac{n}{p^k}\pmod{p}\,.$$
Therefore, $p$ does not divide $\dfrac{h_{1,p^k}}{n}$, whence $p\nmid \dfrac{g_n}{n}$.  Hence, the greatest common divisor of the entries of $\textbf{H}_n=\big(\textbf{A}_n(0)\big)^{-1}$ must be
$$g_n=n\,.$$

Comment: This is great! Indeed, the first row already gives the GCD $n$.